I'm using SQL Alchemy and i'm trying to load XLSX datas into a database
I'm using SQL Alchemy to try to load data into my MySQL Database.
import sys
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

# Define the database URL
DATABASE_URL = ''

# Function to convert date columns
def convert_dates(df, date_columns):
    print(df.columns)
    for col in date_columns:
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').dt.date
    return df

def read_excel_data(file_path):
    sheet_list = ['PERSONNE', 'OEUVRE', 'SOURCE IMPRIMEE', 'SOURCE MANUSCRITE', 'LIEU', 'DÉPÔT', 'COLLECTIVITÉ', 'EVENEMENT']
    classMapping = {
        'PERSONNE': 'Personne',
        'OEUVRE': 'Oeuvre',
        'SOURCE IMPRIMEE': 'SourceImprimee',
        'SOURCE MANUSCRITE': 'SourceManuscrite',
        'LIEU': 'Lieu',
        'DÉPÔT': 'Depot',
        'COLLECTIVITÉ': 'Collectivite',
        'EVENEMENT': 'Evenement'
    }
    attributes_mapping = {
        'PERSONNE': {
            'ID': 'idPersonne',
            'Nom ': 'Nom',
            'Prénom': 'Prénom',
            'Genre': 'Genre',
            'Date de naissance': 'DateNaissance',
            'Date de décès': 'DateDécès',
            'Lieu de naissance': 'LieuNaissance',
            'Lieu de décès': 'LieuDécès',
            'Titres': 'Titres',
            'Fonction': 'Fonction',
            'Rôle sociétaire (période) ': 'RôleSociétaire',
            'Rôle musical (période) ': 'RôleMusical',
            'Portrait\n(optionnel)': 'Portrait',
            'Commentaires publics': 'Commentaires',
        },
        'OEUVRE': {
            'ID': 'idOeuvre',
            'Titre ou [Titre forgé] + sous-titre': 'Titre',
            'Genre musical': 'GenreMusical', 
            'Auteur ou arrangeur du texte (saisie libre)': 'Auteur',
            'Compositeur ou arrangeur de la musique (saisie libre)': 'Compositeur',
            'Date de création ou publication': 'DateCreation', 
            'Source littéraire\n(optionnel)': 'SourceLitteraire',
            'Version (optionnel)': 'Version', 
            'Opus ou livre': 'Opus_ou_livre',
            'N° de catalogue': 'Numero_catalogue', 
            'Commentaires': 'Commentaires',
        },
        'SOURCE IMPRIMEE': {
            'ID': 'idSourceImprimee', 
            'ID Collectivité': 'idCollectivite', 
            'ID Personne (optionnel)': 'idPersonne',
            'ID Evénement (Optionnel)': 'idEvenement',
            'ID Oeuvre (optionnel)': 'idOeuvre',
            'Titre ou [Titre forgé] + sous-titre': 'Titre',
            'Type': 'Type',
            'ID Dépôt': 'idDepot', 
            'Nom de fichier': 'Nom_de_fichier',
            'Lien hypertexte vers la numérisation en ligne si elle existe': 'Lien_hypertexte',
            'Référence (cote)': 'Reference',
            'Année d\'édition': 'Annee_Edition',
            'Description physique': 'Description_Physique',
            'Format réel =pliage\n(optionnel)': 'Format_reel_pliage',
            'Format apparent (optionnel)': 'Format_apparent_cm_x_cm',
            'Pagination (totale ou de l\'extrait)': 'Pagination_totale_ou_extrait',
            'Titre du périodique, du volume ou du recueil': 'Titre_periodique_volume_recueil',
            'Volumaison (Optionnel)': 'Volumaison',
            'Lieu d\'édition': 'Lieu_edition', 
            'Éditeur (optionnel)': 'Editeur',
            'Imprimeur (optionnel)': 'Imprimeur',
            'Lien hypertexte vers notice source\n(uniquement permalien)': 'Lien_hypertexte_vers_notice_source',
            'Transcription (optionnel)\n(nom du pdf) ': 'Transcription_optionnel_nom_pdf',
            'Effectif simplifié (oeuvre musicale)': 'Effectif_simplifie',
            'Commentaires_publics': 'Commentaires',
        },
        'SOURCE MANUSCRITE': {
            'ID': 'idSourceManuscrite', 
            'Contributeur (initiales)': 'Contributeur',
            'Ville': 'Ville',
            'Id Collectivité': 'idCollectivite',
            'Id Personne\n(Optionnel)': 'idPersonne',
            'Id Evénement (Optionnel)': 'idEvenement',
            'Id Oeuvre (Optionnel)': 'idOeuvre',
            'Titre ou [Titre forgé]\n(graphie moderne)': 'Titre',
            'Id Dépôt': 'idDepot',
            'Nom du fichier': 'Nom_de_fichier',
            'Lien hypertexte vers la numérisation en ligne si elle existe': 'Lien hypertexte',
            'Référence (cote)': 'Reference_cote',
            'Type\n(valeurs restreintes)': 'Type',
            'Sous-type': 'SousType',
            'Expression \n(texte original, extraits, fragments composites, arrangement, traduction, édition abrégée...)': 'Expression',
            'Date de production': 'Date_production',
            'Date de modification\n(dernière révision dans le cas de retouches multiples)': 'Date_modification',
            'Description physique': 'DescriptionPhysique',
            'Lien hypertexte vers notice de l\'exemplaire consulté\n(uniquement permalien)': 'LienHypertexte',
            'Transcription (optionnel)\n(nom du pdf) ': 'Transcription',
            'Effectif simplifié (oeuvre musicale) ': 'EffectifSimplifié',
            'Commentaires publics': 'Commentaires'
        },
        'LIEU' : {
            'ID': 'idLieu',
            'ID thesaurus IREMUS \nSera complété par Nathalie Berton-Blivet': 'idThesaurus',
            'Label': 'Label',
            'Terme générique': 'TermeGénérique',
            'Terme spécifique': 'TermeSpécifique',
            'Date de début\n(optionnel)': 'DateDébut', 
            'Date de fin\n(optionnel)': 'DateFin',
            'Commentaires publics': 'Commentaires'
        },
        'DÉPÔT' : {
            'ID': 'idDepot',
            'Label\n(forme d\'autorité - voir CCFR ou à défaut idref) ': 'Label_autorité',
            'Lien hypertexte vers site web': 'Lien_hypertexte',
            'Adresse': 'Adresse_postale',
            'ID Collectivité': 'idCollectivite',
            'Pour mémoire abbréviation utilisée dans le tableau (col. Cote': 'Abbréviation'
        },
        'COLLECTIVITÉ' : {
            'ID': 'idCollectivite',
            'Type': 'Type',
            'Musicale O/N': 'Musicale_ON',
            'Label = Dénomination (+ période)': 'Label_Dénomination_période',
            'IdRef\n(voir site https://www.idref.fr/)': 'IDRef',
            'ID Lieu': 'idLieu',
            'Période d\'activité (Optionnel)': 'Période_activité',
            'Date de reconnaissance (optionnel) ': 'Date_reconnaissance',
            'Devise + traduction + source': 'Devise_traduc_source',
            'Commentaires': 'Commentaires_publics'
        },
        'EVENEMENT' : {
            'ID': 'idEvent',
            'ID Source d\'archive': '',
            'ID Source imprimée': 'idSourceImprimee',
            'ID Oeuvre (optionnel)': 'idOeuvre',
            'ID Personne (optionnel)': 'idPersonne',
            'ID Collectivité (optionnel)': 'idCollectivite',
            'ID Lieu': 'idLieu',
            'Type - sous-type': 'TypeSousType',
            'Périodicité\n(optionnel)': 'Périodicité',
            'Jour de la semaine\n(optionnel)': 'JourSemaine',
            'Date ou date de début': 'DateDébut',
            'Date de fin': 'DateFin',
            'Commentaires publics': 'Commentaires'
        }
    }

    # Load the Excel file
    excel_data = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
    # Create a dictionary to store the dataframes
    df = {}
    # Create a dictionary to store the IDs
    ids = {}
    # Process each sheet
    for sheet in sheet_list:
        df[classMapping[sheet]] = excel_data.parse(sheet)
        sheet_name = sheet
        sheet = classMapping[sheet]

        # Create a dictionary from the ID in df[sheet] to the count in the table
        ids[sheet] = {}
        print(f'Sheet: {sheet}')
        for count, row in df[sheet].iterrows():
            if row['ID'] is None:
                continue
            ids[sheet][row['ID']] = count + 1
            # Replace the ID with the correct ID (count)
            row['ID'] = ids[sheet][row['ID']]
        # Translate the column names to the database column names
        df[sheet] = df[sheet].rename(columns=attributes_mapping[sheet_name])
        df[sheet] = df[sheet].where(pd.notnull(df[sheet]), None)  # Replace NaN with None for SQL compatibility
        # Drop columns which do not translate to the database
        df[sheet] = df[sheet][[x for x in attributes_mapping[sheet_name].values() if x]]  # Keep only the columns that are in the mapping

    # Convert columns that are dates
    df['Personne'] = convert_dates(df['Personne'], ['DateNaissance', 'DateDécès'])
    df['SourceManuscrite'] = convert_dates(df['SourceManuscrite'], ['Date_production', 'Date_modification'])
    df['Evenement'] = convert_dates(df['Evenement'], ['DateDébut', 'DateFin'])
    df['Lieu'] = convert_dates(df['Lieu'], ['DateDébut', 'DateFin'])
    df['Collectivite'] = convert_dates(df['Collectivite'], ['Date_reconnaissance'])

    return df, ids
    
def main():
    # Create the engine and connect to the database
    engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)

    # Reflect the existing database into a new model
    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(engine, only=['personne', 'oeuvre', 'source_imprimee', 'source_manuscrite', 'evenement', 'collectivite', 'lieu', 'depot'])

    # Automap base
    Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)

    # Define the primary tables
    
    class Lieu(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'LIEU'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idLieu = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        pdf_associations = relationship('LieuHasPDF', back_populates='lieu')
    
    class PDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        lieu_associations = relationship('LieuHasPDF', back_populates='pdf')
        evenement_associations = relationship('EvenementHasPDF', back_populates='pdf')
        collectivite_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasPDF', back_populates='pdf')
        source_imprimee_associations = relationship('SourceImprimeeHasPDF', back_populates='pdf')
        source_manuscrite_associations = relationship('SourceManuscriteHasPDF', back_populates='pdf')
        personne_associations = relationship('PersonneHasPDF', back_populates='pdf')
    
    class Evenement(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'EVENEMENT'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idEvent = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        pdf_associations = relationship('EvenementHasPDF', back_populates='evenement')
        personne_associations = relationship('PersonneEvenement', back_populates='evenement')
        oeuvre_associations = relationship('OeuvreEvenement', back_populates='evenement')
    
    class Collectivite(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'COLLECTIVITE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idCollectivite = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        pdf_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasPDF', back_populates='collectivite')
        personne_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasPersonne', back_populates='collectivite')
        depot_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasDepot', back_populates='collectivite')
        source_manuscrite_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasSourceManuscrite', back_populates='collectivite')
        source_imprimee_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasSourceImprimee', back_populates='collectivite')

    class Personne(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        evenement_associations = relationship('PersonneEvenement', back_populates='personne')
        source_imprimee_associations = relationship('SourceImprimeeHasPersonne', back_populates='personne')
        pdf_associations = relationship('PersonneHasPDF', back_populates='personne')
        oeuvre_associations = relationship('PersonneHasOeuvre', back_populates='personne')
        source_manuscrite_associations = relationship('PersonneHasSourceManuscrite', back_populates='personne')
        collectivite_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasPersonne', back_populates='personne')
        relations_a = relationship('PersonnesEnRelationA', foreign_keys='PersonnesEnRelation.idPersonneA', back_populates='personne_a')
        relations_b = relationship('PersonnesEnRelationB', foreign_keys='PersonnesEnRelation.idPersonneB', back_populates='personne_b')
    
    class SourceImprimee(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'SOURCE_IMPRIMEE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        personne_associations = relationship('SourceImprimeeHasPersonne', back_populates='source_imprimee')
        pdf_associations = relationship('SourceImprimeeHasPDF', back_populates='source_imprimee')
        collectivite_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasSourceImprimee', back_populates='source_imprimee')
        oeuvre_associations = relationship('OeuvreSourceManuscriteSourceImprimee', back_populates='source_imprimee')
    
    class SourceManuscrite(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'SOURCE_MANUSCRITE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        pdf_associations = relationship('SourceManuscriteHasPDF', back_populates='source_manuscrite')
        personne_associations = relationship('PersonneHasSourceManuscrite', back_populates='source_manuscrite')
        collectivite_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasSourceManuscrite', back_populates='source_manuscrite')
        oeuvre_associations = relationship('OeuvreSourceManuscriteSourceImprimee', back_populates='source_manuscrite')
    
    class Oeuvre(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'OEUVRE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idOeuvre = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        evenement_associations = relationship('OeuvreEvenement', back_populates='oeuvre')
        personne_associations = relationship('PersonneHasOeuvre', back_populates='oeuvre')
        source_manuscrite_associations = relationship('OeuvreSourceManuscriteSourceImprimee', back_populates='oeuvre')

    class Role(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'ROLE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idRole = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        collectivite_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasPersonne', back_populates='role')
        personne_oeuvre_associations = relationship('PersonneHasOeuvre', back_populates='role')
    
    class Depot(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'DEPOT'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idDepot = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        collectivite_depot_associations = relationship('CollectiviteHasDepot', back_populates='depot')
    
    class LieuHasPDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'LIEU_has_PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idLieuPDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idLieu = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('LIEU.idLieu'))
        idPDF = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PDF.idPDF'))
        lieu = relationship('Lieu', back_populates='pdf_associations')
        pdf = relationship('PDF', back_populates='lieu_associations')
    
    class EvenementHasPDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'EVENEMENT_has_PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idEvenementPDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idEvent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('EVENEMENT.idEvent'))
        idPDF = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PDF.idPDF'))
        evenement = relationship('Evenement', back_populates='pdf_associations')
        pdf = relationship('PDF', back_populates='evenement_associations')

    class CollectiviteHasPDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'COLLECTIVITE_has_PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idCollectivitePDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idCollectivite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('COLLECTIVITE.idCollectivite'))
        idPDF = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PDF.idPDF'))
        collectivite = relationship('Collectivite', back_populates='pdf_associations')
        pdf = relationship('PDF', back_populates='collectivite_associations')
    
    class PersonneEvenement(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNE_EVENEMENT'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonneEvenement = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idEvenement = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('EVENEMENT.idEvent'))
        personne = relationship('Personne', back_populates='evenement_associations')
        evenement = relationship('Evenement', back_populates='personne_associations')
    
    class SourceImprimeeHasPersonne(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'SOURCE_IMPRIMEE_has_PERSONNE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idSourceImprimeePersonne = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_IMPRIMEE.idSourceImprimee'))
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        source_imprimee = relationship('SourceImprimee', back_populates='personne_associations')
        personne = relationship('Personne', back_populates='source_imprimee_associations')
    
    class SourceManuscriteHasPDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'SOURCE_MANUSCRITE_has_PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idSourceManuscritePDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_MANUSCRITE.idSourceManuscrite'))
        idPDF = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PDF.idPDF'))
        source_manuscrite = relationship('SourceManuscrite', back_populates='pdf_associations')
        pdf = relationship('PDF', back_populates='source_manuscrite_associations')

    class SourceImprimeeHasPDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'SOURCE_IMPRIMEE_has_PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idSourceImprimeePDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_IMPRIMEE.idSourceImprimee'))
        idPDF = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PDF.idPDF'))
        source_imprimee = relationship('SourceImprimee', back_populates='pdf_associations')
        pdf = relationship('PDF', back_populates='source_imprimee_associations')
    
    class PersonneHasPDF(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNE_has_PDF'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonnePDF = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idPDF = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PDF.idPDF'))
        personne = relationship('Personne', back_populates='pdf_associations')
        pdf = relationship('PDF', back_populates='personne_associations')
    
    class OeuvreEvenement(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'OEUVRE_EVENEMENT'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idOeuvreEvenement = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idEvent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('EVENEMENT.idEvent'))
        idOeuvre = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('OEUVRE.idOeuvre'))
        evenement = relationship('Evenement', back_populates='oeuvre_associations')
        oeuvre = relationship('Oeuvre', back_populates='evenement_associations')
    
    class CollectiviteHasPersonne(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'COLLECTIVITE_has_PERSONNE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idCollectivitePersonne = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idCollectivite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('COLLECTIVITE.idCollectivite'))
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idRole = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ROLE.idRole'), nullable=True)
        collectivite = relationship('Collectivite', back_populates='personne_associations')
        personne = relationship('Personne', back_populates='collectivite_associations')
        role = relationship('Role', back_populates='collectivite_personne_associations')

    class PersonneHasSourceManuscrite(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNE_has_SOURCE_MANUSCRITE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonneSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_MANUSCRITE.idSourceManuscrite'))
        personne = relationship('Personne', back_populates='source_manuscrite_associations')
        source_manuscrite = relationship('SourceManuscrite', back_populates='personne_associations')
    
    class CollectiviteHasDepot(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'COLLECTIVITE_has_DEPOT'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idCollectiviteDepot = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idCollectivite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('COLLECTIVITE.idCollectivite'))
        idDepot = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('DEPOT.idDepot'))
        collectivite = relationship('Collectivite', back_populates='depot_associations')
        depot = relationship('Depot', back_populates='collectivite_associations')
    
    class CollectiviteHasSourceManuscrite(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'COLLECTIVITE_has_SOURCE_MANUSCRITE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idCollectiviteSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idCollectivite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('COLLECTIVITE.idCollectivite'))
        idSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_MANUSCRITE.idSourceManuscrite'))
        collectivite = relationship('Collectivite', back_populates='source_manuscrite_associations')
        source_manuscrite = relationship('SourceManuscrite', back_populates='collectivite_associations')
    
    class CollectiviteHasSourceImprimee(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'COLLECTIVITE_has_SOURCE_IMPRIMEE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idCollectiviteSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idCollectivite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('COLLECTIVITE.idCollectivite'))
        idSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_IMPRIMEE.idSourceImprimee'))
        collectivite = relationship('Collectivite', back_populates='source_imprimee_associations')
        source_imprimee = relationship('SourceImprimee', back_populates='collectivite_associations')
    
    class OeuvreSourceManuscriteSourceImprimee(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'OEUVRE_SOURCE_MANUSCRITE_SOURCE_IMPRIMEE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idOeuvreSourceManuscriteSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idOeuvre = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('OEUVRE.idOeuvre'))
        idSourceManuscrite = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_MANUSCRITE.idSourceManuscrite'))
        idSourceImprimee = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('SOURCE_IMPRIMEE.idSourceImprimee'))
        oeuvre = relationship('Oeuvre', back_populates='source_manuscrite_associations')
        source_manuscrite = relationship('SourceManuscrite', back_populates='oeuvre_associations')
        source_imprimee = relationship('SourceImprimee', back_populates='oeuvre_associations')
    
    class PersonnesEnRelationA(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNES_en_relation'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonneRelation = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idPersonneA = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idPersonneB = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        personne_a = relationship('Personne', foreign_keys=[idPersonneA], back_populates='relations_a')
        personne_b = relationship('Personne', foreign_keys=[idPersonneB], back_populates='relations_b')
    
    class PersonnesEnRelationB(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNES_en_relation'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonneRelation = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idPersonneA = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idPersonneB = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        personne_a = relationship('Personne', foreign_keys=[idPersonneA], back_populates='relations_a')
        personne_b = relationship('Personne', foreign_keys=[idPersonneB], back_populates='relations_b')
    
    class PersonneHasOeuvre(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'PERSONNE_has_OEUVRE'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        idPersonneOeuvre = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        idPersonne = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PERSONNE.idPersonne'))
        idOeuvre = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('OEUVRE.idOeuvre'))
        idRole = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ROLE.idRole'), nullable=True)
        personne = relationship('Personne', back_populates='oeuvre_associations')
        oeuvre = relationship('Oeuvre', back_populates='personne_associations')
        role = relationship('Role', back_populates='oeuvre_associations')


    # Prepare the base
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

    # Create a session
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # Print out the mapped classes
    print("Mapped classes:")
    for class_name in Base.classes.keys():
        print(class_name)

    # Load the Excel files
    files = ['Carpentras_normalisee_27_05_2024.xlsx']
    session.query(Personne).delete()
    for f in files:
        df, ids = read_excel_data(f)

        for _, row in df['Personne'].iterrows():
            new_record = Personne(**row.to_dict())
            session.add(new_record)
            print('new_record: ', new_record.__dict__)
        session.commit()

    # Query the first 5 records from the 'personne' table
    results = session.query(Personne).limit(5).all()
    for record in results:
        print(record.__dict__)

    # Close the session
    session.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Code looks like this (with the connection to the database of course)
I'm having this error : sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'PERSONNES_en_relation' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
Can somebody help me? And can somebody review the general structure of my code or tell me what i'm doing wrong. I am still learning and i have some issues.
Thanks you !
I'm expecting the script to load the data in the database.

Try moving Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True) to before you define the model classes. (The main reason for using automap is to avoid having to define classes for existing tables, you might want to consider whether you need all these model declarations)
